# C - recursive function for sum of n natural numbers

Tags: c, recursion

Below is the recursive function for sum of natural numbers up to `n`.

```
int calculateSum(int n) {
    if (n == 0){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return n + calculateSum(--n); //Replacing --n with n-1 works
    }
}
```

Input: 5

If I **use `--n`** then the **output is 10**, but when I **replace `--n` with `n - 1`** then the correct result is returned (15). Why the difference?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior-in-c  ?

Comment: @Yunnosch in principle it is, but it isn't *that* obvious...

Comment: Saying "it is UB, that's why" really would be unsatisfying, but I cannot imagine even one nasal demon getting close to explaining it.

Comment: @Yunnosch yea, that question is reserved for the duplicates of form: "please explain the output of the following code excerpt"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As surprising as it might be, the behaviour of the expression

```
n + calculateSum(--n);
```

is *undefined*, because `--n` not only evaluates to the value of `n` after being decremented by 1, it also changes `n` to the new value. The change (a side effect), however, is *unsequenced* in relation to the *other* evaluation of `n`  (a value computation) on the left. And according to [C11 Appendix J.2.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2), the behaviour is undefined, when

> A side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object [(6.5)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p2).

More of the same class of errors in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior-in-c).

---

You can consider yourself lucky when you got a wrong value, because your compiler could have also generated code that would return the *"correct value"*... given the phase of the moon, and the optimization settings, or the number of lines in the calling function...

Answer (score 4):

`--n` also modifies the local variable `n`; the expression `n-1` just returns the decremented value to pass it on to the recursive call, but does not modify your input-parameter.

In detail for the first iteration with input `5`:

- Correct is `return 5 + calculateSum(5-1);`
- With `--n` you would also decrement from `n` and end up with `4 + calculateSum(4)`

@user3386109 & @Yunnosch worded it this way: 
With `--n` you calculate the sum `0...(5-1)` instead of `0...5`.

See @Antti answer, it explains that it's actually undefined behaviour.

Comment: Please go on with the explanation. How does this cause the observed behaviour?

Comment: I added what can happen in the first iteration. Also see @Antti answer, it explains that it's actually undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Yunnosch It does explain 10, because it's calculating 4+3+2+1+0 instead of 5+4+3+2+1. Of course, that doesn't change the fact that it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Damn, my mistake. Sorry.

Comment: However, I recommend to move the mentioning of UB (via referring to Anttis answer, or directly) into the answer, instead of keeping it in a comment (which theoretically will be deleted at some point).

Comment: In case you want to rub in my thinking mistake (you have earned that privilege ;-) ), explain that with `--n` the value of calculateSum(4) is the sum of all integers 0...(4-1), not 0...4. I was blind on that eye and therefor failed to understand your otherwise good explanation. You might make your answer more impressive that way. (You already have my upvote by the way, I appreciate people who find my mistakes.)

Answer (score -1):

The following code snippet (a Function), you can call it in the main function which will return the sum of n natural numbers recursively

```
int NNumbers(int n)
{
    if(n != 0)
        return n + NNumbers(n-1);
    else
        return n;
}
```

In your code you are decrementing the value of n and then you are calculating the sum (i,e. Pre-Decrement), since the input is 5, it decrements 1 at each iteration and and then it will go for addition of natural numbers. so you are getting the result 10 instead of 15

Hope this helps for you :)

Thank you

Comment: OP was already aware of the correct solution and only asked for an explanation of the result of the wrong method. This is therefor not answering the question.

Comment: yes @Yunnosch i just submitted my answer before explanation, please have a look at my explanation and correct me if i am going wrong anywhere

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see how this answer gives any additional insight in comparison to the older answers and it still consists mostly of a solution that was not asked for.

Comment: If anything the explanation is misleading, mostly since there's no mention of UB (merely adding that mention won't make this more insightful than either of the other answers).